# Sending Salesforce web-to-lead form data programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, salesforce

Salesforce has a feature that gives you the ability to insert a web-to-lead form on your site. It's just a form with the action set to a servlet url, that the form posts the data to.

I have an existing contact form on my site. I can't modify the form at all, but I can capture the submit event of the form and add custom functionality when the form is submitted.

Is there an API method or some other way that I can programatically post the form data the same way as the Salesforce web-to-lead form does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce.com does indeed have an API that will allow you to insert that lead from the contact form.  See [the .net section of http://developer.force.com](http://events.developerforce.com/en/pages/force-dot-com-dot-net) for lots of info and code samples on using the API from .net.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately I couldn't find anything related to using the API to submit the contact form data. Do you have a link for that?

Comment: You'll find a relevant code sample at the bottom of this page: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm#kanchor384